# Will Random.Next ever stop being random?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create random numbers between 0 and upto 2 so I am using:

```
//field level
private static Random _random = new Random();

//used in a method
_random.Next(0, 2)
```

My question is: will the sequence ever repeat / stop been random? Should I recreate (`_random = new Random();`) every day?

Comment: Yes, the sequence will repeat eventually, as it is not *actually* random.

Comment: Philosophical Question: Is anything ever truly random or just the result of the butterfly effect? ;)

Comment: @Gabe If the period had been equal to the duration (in time) of our universe, would it be random or non-random? At some point something is random "enough". You have made a p => q, but the p (it's not actually random) doesn't need to "point" to q, OR you could consider our universe to be "not random"... Ok... we are going too much philosophical here... :-)

Comment: If speed and security are not concerns, System.Math.Random is fine. If you want less predictable numbers, consider using somethign like CSPRandomNumberGenerator (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is fine as it is.

You do not need to create a new `Random` object daily.

Note that `Random` is not truly random, but produces a pseudo-random result.

Comment: In fact, generating a new Random object, if done within a second with the previous, will generate the same Random object and you will keep getting the same values

Answer (score 4):

If you check the 'remarks' section [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) you will find that System.Random is a pseudo-random generator.

This means in theory the sequence does eventually repeat. In practice it very much depends on what you're doing as to how much this matters. For example, the length of the sequence is such that no human will ever notice them repeating. On the otherhand, it's pretty useless for cryptography.

Edit to add: restarting daily won't make much difference. Either the pseudo-randomness is sufficient for you or you need to look into cryptographically secure way of generating random numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Math.Random returns a 32-bit signed integer, it will repeat on the 2^32'nd call if you dont reseed. If you DO reseed it will repeat itself sooner.

Comment: I don't believe this is true: you might get a repeat value well before the 2^32 value, but the sequence is significantly longer than that.

Comment: They use an LCG. For LCG look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Comment: My bad. I had (mis)remembered that they used a Mersenne twister, but it appears I was thinking of Python.

Comment: What makes you think they use an LCG? According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117654/will-random-next-ever-stop-been-randon/5117777#5117777 they use an LFG which has a much longer period.

Answer (score 2):

Random is not *that* random. If you need "more" random, you should have a look a cryptographic classes, such as [RandomNumberGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator.aspx) (abstract), for example: [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you read this, you'll see that Random is (currently) based on `the subtractive lagged Fibonacci generator of (24, 55)` which should guarantee the period to be at least 2^55 . BUT if you look at the end of the page, someone has pointed to a possible bug (the comment of `ytosa` on October 2010)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.100).aspx

Lets say that the period is long enough unless you need to do "special" applications!

I will add that the Wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagged_Fibonacci_generator tells us there is a paper that shows that the 24, 55 sequence of lagged Fibonacci isn't "random enough" (under `Problems with LFG`)

Comment: The reference link doesn't show any comments. This bug report by ytosa should explain the issue well enough: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634761/system-random-serious-bug

Comment: @Levitikon You have to select as the version 4.0... and the author was ytosa and not tosa... So as of now the correct link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to generate cryptographically secure random numbers, you should probably use a better PRNG. If you just want the occasional random number and true randomness isn't critical (which I imagine given the output values range) then your code is most likely just fine as it is.

Answer (score 0):

It worth mention (at list by my experience) that if you have a **method** when you declare :

```
 Random myRand=new Random();
 myRand.Next(10);  
 //...doing somthing with that
```

and then, if you call this method many times (in a loop) , you might ends up with a lot of duplicates results. (that what happend to me).

and the solution I found was to move `Random myRand=new Random()` to be a **class** member initiation statment ( instead of a local variable of a **method**),  match like you did.

after that , there were no longer duplicated results